# Android Studio - automatically start DDMS and emulator with launch, and auto clear logcat in DDMS

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, ddms

Two questions here:

1) When I start Android Studio, I always have to manually start my emulator and DDMS after that. Is there a way to automate this procedure and have them automatically start up when I launch Android Studio?

2) Is there a way to auto clear logcat in DDMS each time I run my app? I know how to have it auto clear in Android Studio via Preferences, but that doesn't seem to apply to DDMS.

Comment: are you using mac ? or windows ?

Comment: its the same idea for windows. Just the script would be different and paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your linux terminal go to /usr/local/bin folder. Create a file called mystudio and put in the commands to run android studio and monitor.  Change the permission of the file like this:  chmond +x mystudio.  To run the file just type mystudio from anywhere since its in the bin folder.

steps: The command to start studio from command line has to be created first. In android studio go to tools --> Create command line launcher:
[image]

You'll see a window asking what you want to call it, you can just leave it as is and hit enter:
[image]

Now you can open android studio alone from the command line anywhere by typing studio.  Now lets write the shell script to open ddms at the same time:

Create this file: /usr/local/bin/mystudio
and enter in the following info:

```
    #!/bin/bash
studio;monitor
adb logcat -c
```

save and close.  Change the permissions on the file by:

```
chmod +x mystudio
```

Finally type mystudio on the command line and both ddms and android studio open at the same time.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So basically I would need to create my own script, there is no option in Android Studio for either of the above?

Comment: after android studio creates the studio script. you can go into it and at the end put "monitor;adb logcat -c"  but you still have to run it from the command line.  YOu can create a batch file to run your script in windows though. I dont know if there is another way.